# Get URL content with Basic Authentication with Java and async-http-client

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I am writing a Java lib and need to perform a request to a URL - currently using [async-http-client](https://github.com/asynchttpclient/async-http-client/) from ning - and fetch its content. So I have a `get` method that returns a String
of the content of the fetched document. However, to be able to get it, I must perform a HTTP basic authentication and I'm not succeeding at this in my Java code:

```
public String get(String token) throws IOException {
    String fetchURL = "https://www.eventick.com.br/api/v1/events/492";

    try {
        String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(token + ":", "UTF-8");
        return this.asyncClient.prepareGet(fetchURL)
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded).execute().get().getResponseBody();
    }
}
```

The code returns no error, it just doesn't fetch the URL because the authentication header is not being properly set, somehow.

With curl `-u` option I can easily get what I want:

`curl https://www.eventick.com.br/api/v1/events/492 -u 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:'`

Returns:

```
{"events":[{"id":492,"title":"Festa da Bagaceira","venue":"Mangueirão de Paulista",
"slug":"bagaceira-fest", "start_at":"2012-07-29T16:00:00-03:00",
"links":{"tickets":[{"id":738,"name":"Normal"}]}}]}
```

How can this be done in Java? With the async-http-client lib? Or if you know how to do it using another way..

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. You need to base 64 encode rather than URL encode. That is, you need

```
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user + ':' + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

rather than

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(token + ":", "UTF-8");
```

(Note that for the benefit of others, since I'm answering 2 years later, in my answer I'm using the more standard `"user:password"` whereas your question has `"token:"`. If `"token:"` is what you needed, then stick with that. But maybe that was part of the problem, too?)

Here is a short, self-contained, correct example

```
package so17380731;

import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;

public class BasicAuth {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        try(AsyncHttpClient asyncClient = new AsyncHttpClient()) {
            final String user = "StackOverflow";
            final String password = "17380731";
            final String fetchURL = "https://www.eventick.com.br/api/v1/events/492";
            final String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((user + ':' + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            final String body = asyncClient
                .prepareGet(fetchURL)
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encoded)
                .execute()
                .get()
                .getResponseBody(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            System.out.println(body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And, speaking of 2 years later, the original question was asked on my 40th birthday. Ugh. Time flies

Comment: Thanks you so much! I've spend 3 hours trying probably 20 different solutions. Not only does it work properly but it's also much simpler than anything else I've found. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is very sketchy, but I think that you need to use a `RequestBuilder` following the pattern shown in the [`Request`](http://sonatype.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/Request.html) javadoc:

```
Request r = new RequestBuilder().setUrl("url")
    .setRealm((new Realm.RealmBuilder()).setPrincipal(user)
    .setPassword(admin)
    .setRealmName("MyRealm")
    .setScheme(Realm.AuthScheme.DIGEST).build());
r.execute();
```

(Obviously, this example is not Basic Auth, but there are clues as to how you would do it.)

---

FWIW, one problem with your current code is that a Basic Auth header uses base64 encoding not URL encoding; see the [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) for details.

Answer (score 2):

basically, do it like this:

`BoundRequestBuilder request = asyncHttpClient
      .preparePost(getUrl())
      .setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
      .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .setRealm(org.asynchttpclient.Dsl.basicAuthRealm(getUser(), getPassword())) 
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^-- this is the important part
      .setBody(json);`

Test can be found here:
https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/test/java/org/asynchttpclient/BasicAuthTest.java

Answer (score 0):

This is also another way of adding Basic Authorization,
you can use any of two the classes for your use AsyncHttpClient,HttpClient,in this case i will use AsyncHttpClient

```
AsyncHttpClient client=new AsyncHttpClient();           
        Request request = client.prepareGet("https://www.eventick.com.br/api/v1/events/492").
            setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
            .setHeader("Authorization","Basic b2pAbml1LXR2LmNvbTpnMGFRNzVDUnhzQ0ZleFQ=")
            .setBody(jsonObjectRepresentation.toString()).build();
```

after adding header part

```
            ListenableFuture<Response> r = null;
            //ListenableFuture<Integer> f= null;
            try{
            r = client.executeRequest(request);
            System.out.println(r.get().getResponseBody());
            }catch(IOException e){

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client.close();
```

it may be useful for you

Comment: Classes AsyncHttpClient,ListenableFuture are available in async-http-client-1.7.5.jar you can download it form http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadasynchttpclient175jar.htm