# Sending multi part form data in post method in play/scala

Tags: scala, playframework

How can I  send multi part form data in post method in play scala
using : scalaVersion:2.11.7
playVersion-2.1.5

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaFileUpload?

Comment: yes I have seen this documentation this is for file upload I want to send some other fields as form data in post ,I am able to send data in json form but in form- data I don't know how to send in post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a little code, then you can use it like

```
val data = MultipartFormData(formFields, "asdasboundarystringas")
WS.url(myUrl).post(data.body)
```

The code of MultipartFormData you can find on the github: https://gist.github.com/EECOLOR/7649144

**UPDATE**

Another method, I have been try it with Play 2.4.3

```
package controllers

import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart
import java.io.File

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val url = "http://symlink.dk/code/php/submit/"

    val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying
    val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost("http://symlink.dk/code/php/submit/")
    val builder = postBuilder.addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField", "abc", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField1", "abc1", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField2", "abc2", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new FilePart("myFile", new File("app/controllers/Application.scala")))
    val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();
    Ok(response.getResponseBody)
  }

}
```

Symlink does not verify file part, so I am not sure about it, but fileds definitely was send

**UPDATE**

With Authentication and file verification

```
package controllers

import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val url = "http://httpbin.org/post"

    val name = "MyUserName"
    val password = "MyPassword"

    val encodedCredentials =
      new String(encodeBase64("%s:%s".format(name, password).getBytes))

    val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying
    val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)
    val builder = postBuilder
      .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials)
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField", "abc", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField1", "abc1", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("myField2", "abc2", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new FilePart("myFile", new File("app/controllers/Application.scala")))
    val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();
    Ok(response.getResponseBody)
  }

}
```

Echo of posted data:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "myFile": "package controllers\n\nimport play.api.Play.current\nimport play.api.libs.ws._\nimport play.api._\nimport play.api.mvc._\nimport com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient\nimport com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart\nimport com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart\nimport java.io.File\nimport org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64\n\nclass Application extends Controller {\n\n  def index = Action {\n//    val url = \"http://symlink.dk/code/php/submit/\"\n    val url = \"http://httpbin.org/post\"\n\n    val name = \"MyUserName\"\n    val password = \"MyPassword\"\n\n    val encodedCredentials =\n      new String(encodeBase64(\"%s:%s\".format(name, password).getBytes))\n\n    val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying\n    val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)\n    val builder = postBuilder\n      .addHeader(\"Authorization\", \"Basic \" + encodedCredentials)\n      .addBodyPart(new StringPart(\"myField\", \"abc\", \"UTF-8\"))\n      .addBodyPart(new StringPart(\"myField1\", \"abc1\", \"UTF-8\"))\n      .addBodyPart(new StringPart(\"myField2\", \"abc2\", \"UTF-8\"))\n      .addBodyPart(new FilePart(\"myFile\", new File(\"app/controllers/Application.scala\")))\n    val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();\n    Ok(response.getResponseBody)\n  }\n\n}\n"
  }, 
  "form": {
    "myField": "abc", 
    "myField1": "abc1", 
    "myField2": "abc2"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Authorization": "Basic TXlVc2VyTmFtZTpNeVBhc3N3b3Jk", 
    "Content-Length": "1991", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=ZUeOacX0k9AyI7O12kXDuV5gucDyh2IcA", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "AHC/1.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "111.111.111.11", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

**UPDATE**

just for clarification - if you do not need to send  file as part of the form then you do not need to access underlying WSClient and can use trivial WS

```
val url = "http://httpbin.org/post"

val name = "MyUserName"
val password = "MyPassword"

val result = WS.url(url)
  .withAuth(name, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
  .post(
      Map(
        "myField" -> Seq("myValue"),
        "myField1" -> Seq("myValue1"),
        "myField2" -> Seq("myValue2")
      )
    )
val response = Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
Ok(response.body)
```

request that this code send:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "myField": "myValue", 
    "myField1": "myValue1", 
    "myField2": "myValue2"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Authorization": "Basic TXlVc2VyTmFtZTpNeVBhc3N3b3Jk", 
    "Content-Length": "51", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "AHC/1.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "111.111.111.11", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) but can u give me one template code and one controller class code

Comment: I can tell  you my exactly requirements is this I have four fields: file which is I am taking from form and other three fields are static I want to send all these four field as form data in post url  ws.url(myurl).post(data) but here data how I can send in mutli part form data in post what I need to give in this data can u tell me

Comment: these two links I am using for solving my problem But this code is not working for me it is giving error type mismatch; found : com.ning.http.client.FluentCaseInsensitiveStringsMap required: com.ning.http.client.FluentStringsMap

Comment: well, it looks like they add support of multipart to the play a year ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/MPtQlX-cWMQ/rdabLhGwytcJ mb it will help you

Comment: look on the update part - I did verification on my own project. Could you try it on 2.1.5 ? Or mb you would like to migrate on 2.4 :)

Comment: hey in your update part how will I add authentication for particular  url

Comment: I suppose you are talking about basic authorization. This post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380731/get-url-content-with-basic-authentication-with-java-and-async-http-client I could look later in details how to translate this java to scala if you hard with this

Comment: thanks but in your update part code can u tell me where I need to add  authentications details

Comment: with play 2.1.5 it s not working when I am adding this com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient related jar to build.scala then play is unable to get data

Comment: when I am using play 2.4.3 and jdk 1.7 it is telling java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:com/typesafe/config/ConfigExceptionsupported major.minor version 52.0
        unable to load project

Comment: It's because ply 2.4 requires JDK 8. You can not run  it's on jdk 1.7 sorry :(

Comment: when I am using jdk 1.8 then other problem is coming I tried with 1.8 also

Comment: I am unable to create war file in 2.1.5 that's why I switched to play 2.4.3  in ubuntu  and  now this same code is not working it is telling 400 bad request can u please tell me what is wrong I am doing.

Comment: I verify it on the 2.4.3 (I am on mac) - it works. Can you create another question with the exactly code you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965746/error-in-sending-data-as-multi-form-data-in-play-scala I posted here can U tell me what I am missing

Comment: hey an u reply for this question given link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200986/how-to-send-forms-element-data-in-controller-classin-play-scala

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Andriy Kuba!

I've made some changes (WS.client.underlying didn't work for me)
I m running with play 2.4.

```
package utils

import com.ning.http.client.{AsyncHttpClient, ListenableFuture, Request, Response}
import com.ning.http.client.cookie.Cookie
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.{FilePart, StringPart}

/**
  * Created by ozma on 27/05/16.
  */
object WsExtend {

  def postFile(url: String,
               files: List[(String, String)] = List(),
               bodyParams: List[(String, String)] = List(),
               cookies: List[Cookie] = List(),
               headers: Map[String, String] = Map(),
               encoding: String = "UTF-8"): Response = {
    postFileAsync(url, files, bodyParams, cookies, headers, encoding).get()
  }

  def postFileAsync(url: String,
                    files: List[(String, String)] = List(),
                    bodyParams: List[(String, String)] = List(),
                    cookies: List[Cookie] = List(),
                    headers: Map[String, String] = Map(),
                    encoding: String = "UTF-8"): ListenableFuture[Response] = {
    val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient()
    val postBuilder: AsyncHttpClient#BoundRequestBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)
    files.foreach(e => postBuilder.addBodyPart(new FilePart(e._1, new java.io.File(e._2))))
    bodyParams.foreach(e =>  postBuilder.addBodyPart(new StringPart(e._1, e._2, encoding)))
    cookies.foreach(c => postBuilder.addCookie(c))
    headers.foreach(h => postBuilder.addHeader(h._1, h._2))
    val request: Request = postBuilder.build()
    asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(request)
  }
}
```

This is how I used it with Silhouette CookieAuthenticator

"**cookie**" is a header called "**Set-Cookie**" from login response.

```
WsExtend.postFile(
      url=url,
      files = List("fileparamname" -> filepath),
      bodyParams = List("albumName" -> albumName),
      headers = Map("Cookie" -> cookie)
```