# Error in sending data as multi form data in play /scala

Tags: scala, rest, playframework

This is my code the same code is working in play 2.1.5 but I am unable to create war file in play 2.1.5 so I switched to play 2.4.3 and now in response it is coming that `400 bad request client` is sending wrong syntactically even post rest api is not hitting. Can some tell me what I am missing?

```
import play.api._
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.mvc._
//import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.api.libs.ws.WSAuthScheme
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }



def postUpload=Action(parse.multipartFormData){request=>

   val groupingType= request.body.dataParts("Grouping type").mkString
    val email=request.body.dataParts("NotificationRecepients").mkString
    val custId=request.body.dataParts("CustomerId").mkString
    val custIdFinal:Int=custId.toInt


   request.body.file("file").map { file =>

  val file1=file.ref.file.getAbsolutePath;


  val fileName = file.filename 
    val contentType = file.contentType

  //file.ref.moveTo(new File("/home/kanchan/Desktop/"+fileName),true)


     val user = "myUser";
      val password = "myPassword";

 val encodedCredentials =
      new String(encodeBase64("%s:%s".format(user, password).getBytes))

    val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient =WS.client.underlying
    val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)
    val builder = postBuilder
      .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials)
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedGroupType", "Functional Grouping", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("mailRecipients", "kancgupt@cisco.com", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedFile", "Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx", "UTF-8"))
      .addBodyPart(new FilePart("file",new File("/home/kanchan/Downloads/Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx")))

    val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();
   Ok(response.getResponseBody)


  }.getOrElse {

     Ok( "Missing file")

  }
}
}
```

Play version 2.4.3
sbt:0.13.8

getting following error:
Apache Tomcat/6.0.39 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request

**type** Status report

**message** Bad Request

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.39

Comment: It's not clear where is 400 error come. As I see it could be because you send a bad request to your "postUpload" action. I verify your data - it's works well. So I suppose the problem is exactly in your request to your server. Can you run WS send part just with the test data, without parsing your own request ?

Comment: If I am sending wrong request I t should not work in play 2.1.5 right but it is working fine that means I am sending request in correct way and my get rest api thorugh WS it is also working correctly

Comment: my post rest api is working correctly in post man rest client

Comment: create just simple test with sending your data. I did it - it works with your data (of course I use my own file). I did verification against http://httpbin.org/post - it process request correctly. So I suppose the error is in the another part of your system

Comment: problem with server side or my code because same code is working in play 2.1.5 I am unable to understand

Comment: You need to split issue in to sub issues to detect exactly the place of the problem: 1) process the request; 2) send the form with WS; 3) process the request on the thrd side.  It very low probability that you will receive the answer to this question until you break the question. The reason is - 400 could be on any of this 3 steps. I could say only that I verify point "2" on Play 2.4.3 and it works.

Comment: I found problem what ever I am sending data in body part it is not getting anything don't know while in header what ever I am sending it is going

Comment: [com.ning.http.client.StringPart@44c642d7, com.ning.http.client.StringPart@344e5487, com.ning.http.client.StringPart@28f85e5, com.ning.http.client.FilePart@1c9f7eb3] this I should get but I am getting

Comment: with play 2.4.3 I am getting this [StringPart name=selectedGroupType contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=mailRecipients contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=selectedFile contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, FilePart name=file contentType=application/octet-stream charset=null tranferEncoding=binary contentId=null dispositionType=null filename=Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx

Comment: everything is null don't know why

Comment: with play 2.4.3 there is some problem with com.ning.http.client.multipart

Answer (score 0):

You describing something really strange. I took your code, curl, REST server echo (http://httpbin.org, exactly  http://httpbin.org/post url), create new play-scala application with the 2.4.3 play. It works like a charm.

Code:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.libs.ws._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.api.libs.ws.WSAuthScheme
import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart
import com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart
import java.io.File
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64

class Original extends Controller {

  def postUpload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>

    val groupingType = request.body.dataParts("Groupingtype").mkString
    val email = request.body.dataParts("NotificationRecepients").mkString
    val custId = request.body.dataParts("CustomerId").mkString
    val custIdFinal: Int = custId.toInt

    request.body.file("file").map { file =>

      val file1 = file.ref.file.getAbsolutePath;

      val fileName = file.filename
      val contentType = file.contentType

      val url = "http://httpbin.org/post"

      val user = "myUser";
      val password = "myPassword";

      val encodedCredentials =
        new String(encodeBase64("%s:%s".format(user, password).getBytes))

      val asyncHttpClient: AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying
      val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)
      val builder = postBuilder
        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials)
        .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedGroupType", groupingType, "UTF-8"))
        .addBodyPart(new StringPart("mailRecipients", email, "UTF-8"))
        .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedFile", fileName, "UTF-8"))
        .addBodyPart(new FilePart("file", new File(file1)))

      val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();
      Ok(response.getResponseBody)

    }.getOrElse {

      Ok("Missing file")

    }
  }
}
```

curl command (from the project root folder):

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
   -F "Groupingtype=Groupingtype" \
   -F "NotificationRecepients=NotificationRecepients" \
   -F "CustomerId=123" \
   -F "file=@app/controllers/Application.scala" \
 'http://localhost:9000/post'
```

curl response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 18:38:11 GMT
Content-Length: 3122

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "file": "package controllers..."
  }, 
  "form": {
    "mailRecipients": "NotificationRecepients", 
    "selectedFile": "Application.scala", 
    "selectedGroupType": "Groupingtype"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Authorization": "Basic bXlVc2VyOm15UGFzc3dvcmQ=", 
    "Content-Length": "3215", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=2EmAF3UE9xSuA6KQpUS3q-Ohzkp0f_7-8", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "AHC/1.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "111.111.111.111", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Try to create new simple project and use my code - then migrate yours in to this new project - maybe you will find something. It could be some wrong migration steps from 2.1.5 or so.

my *build.sbt*

```
name := """scala-send-multipart-clean"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

my *project/plugins.sbt*

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
```

my *project/build.properties*

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Wed Oct 07 00:44:35 EEST 2015
template.uuid=7da33b5a-3aef-4d2e-b318-dae93632b999
sbt.version=0.13.8
```

**java version "1.8.0_40"**, updated to the **"build 1.8.0_60-b27"** - no difference.

> I am getting this [StringPart name=selectedGroupType contentType=UTF-8
>   charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null
>   dispositionType=null, StringPart name=mailRecipients contentType=UTF-8
>   charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null
>   dispositionType=null, StringPart name=selectedFile contentType=UTF-8
>   charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null
>   dispositionType=null, FilePart name=file
>   contentType=application/octet-stream charset=null
>   tranferEncoding=binary contentId=null dispositionType=null
>   filename=Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx]

It is the way `toString` is realised in the **Parts**. That's all, it does not tell something about "correct" or "not correct".

My results for

```
println(builder.build().getParts())
```

is

```
[StringPart name=selectedGroupType contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=mailRecipients contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=selectedFile contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, FilePart name=file contentType=application/octet-stream charset=null tranferEncoding=binary contentId=null dispositionType=null filename=multipartBody1697314279257602964asTemporaryFile]
```

As you see it very similar to yours, but if you will output names and values for the string part, I am pretty sure you will receive both:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

... 

builder.build().getParts().map{ part =>
    if(part.isInstanceOf[StringPart]){
      val stringPart: StringPart = part.asInstanceOf[StringPart]
      println(stringPart.getName() + ":" + stringPart.getValue())
    }
}
```

results:

```
selectedGroupType:Groupingtype
mailRecipients:NotificationRecepients
selectedFile:Application.scala
```

Comment: Do I need to add lib dependency in play 2.4.3 for com.ning.hhtp.client.multipart and org.apache.commons.codec package we don't need to add right? it comes automatically in play 2.4.3. right?

Comment: yes, I did only two things: add Original.scala file - it in the my post and add "POST    /post                           controllers.Original.postUpload" record to the rotes file

Comment: I have checked my all three steps actually in second part only what ever I have done in add body part it is going null don't know why when I checked build.build() output in header what I am giving it is taking but in body part whatever I am giving it is not taking

Comment: I am getting this [StringPart name=selectedGroupType contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=mailRecipients contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, StringPart name=selectedFile contentType=UTF-8 charset=US-ASCII tranferEncoding=8bit contentId=null dispositionType=null, FilePart name=file contentType=application/octet-stream charset=null tranferEncoding=binary contentId=null dispositionType=null filename=Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx

Comment: I should not get this right? I should get sth like this [com.ning.http.client.StringPart@44c642d7, com.ning.http.client.StringPart@344e5487, com.ning.http.client.StringPart@28f85e5, com.ning.http.client.FilePart@1c9f7eb3]

Comment: all data I can pass in header but not file  do u have any idea how can I pass file in other different way

Comment: same multipart is working in play 2.1.5 with ws.client I think with 2.4.3 there is some problem with WS.client.underlying

Comment: hey can u tell me what scala version and sbt version u are using

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.11.6", 
sbt.version=0.13.8, java version "1.8.0_40" - I updated my post

Comment: same versions of sbt and scala I am using except java version 1.8_60

Comment: look at my "debug" updated in to the post - right after the java version

Comment: hey do u have any idea how to resolve time out exception :play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response received after 120000

Comment: So you fought 400 error :) "TimeoutException" - could be anything. You need to show at least the action code, mb some ws call is too long.

Comment: no in webservice log I checked webservice is complete in 1 min ,also giving response  but in action code it is not getting response don't know why,web service is not that long

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076389/java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception-in-play-2-1-5 where I posted this question

Comment: my webservice is giving response in 4000ms only don't know why play not getting response.

Comment: I think async-http-client issues which is related to timeouts:

Comment: can u reply for this question given link below  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200986/how-to-send-forms-element-data-in-controller-classin-play-scala