# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException in play 2.1.5

Tags: scala, rest, playframework

```
    import play.api._
    import play.api.libs.ws._
    import play.api.mvc._
    //import javax.inject.Inject
    import play.api.Play.current
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import play.api.libs.ws.WSAuthScheme
    import com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient
    import com.ning.http.client.multipart.FilePart
    import com.ning.http.client.multipart.StringPart
    import java.io.File
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64

    class Application extends Controller {

      def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
      }



    def postUpload=Action(parse.multipartFormData){request=>

       val groupingType= request.body.dataParts("Grouping type").mkString
        val email=request.body.dataParts("NotificationRecepients").mkString
        val custId=request.body.dataParts("CustomerId").mkString
        val custIdFinal:Int=custId.toInt


       request.body.file("file").map { file =>

      val file1=file.ref.file.getAbsolutePath;


      val fileName = file.filename 
        val contentType = file.contentType

      //file.ref.moveTo(new File("/home/kanchan/Desktop/"+fileName),true)

    val url="myUrl";
         val user = "myUser";
          val password = "myPassword";

     val encodedCredentials =
          new String(encodeBase64("%s:%s".format(user, password).getBytes))

        val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient =WS.client.underlying
        val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(url)
        val builder = postBuilder
          .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials)
          .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedGroupType", "Functional Grouping", "UTF-8"))
          .addBodyPart(new StringPart("mailRecipients", "kancgupt@cisco.com", "UTF-8"))
          .addBodyPart(new StringPart("selectedFile", "Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx", "UTF-8"))
          .addBodyPart(new FilePart("file",new File("/home/kanchan/Downloads/Sample_group_upload_file.xlsx")))

        val response = asyncHttpClient.executeRequest(builder.build()).get();
       Ok(response.getResponseBody)


      }.getOrElse {

         Ok( "Missing file")

      }
    }
    }
```

This code is working for one rest api but when I am calling another webservice I am getting this error stack trace:

```
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.util.conc
urrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response re
ceived after 120000
[error] application -

! @6nmc6dl9k - Internal server error, for (POST) [/uploads] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ExecutionException: java.util
.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response received after 120000]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:287) ~[play_
2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:381) [play_
2.10.jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleActi
on$1$2$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:413) [play_2.10.
jar:2.1.5]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleActi
on$1$2$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:413) [play_2.10.
jar:2.1.5]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleActi
on$1$2.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:413) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.5]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException:
No response received after 120000
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyRes
ponseFuture.java:223) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyRes
ponseFuture.java:187) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(
Application.scala:123) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(
Application.scala:88) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1.apply(Application.scala
:88) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response received after 120
000
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyRes
ponseFuture.java:215) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
        at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyRes
ponseFuture.java:187) ~[async-http-client.jar:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(
Application.scala:123) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(
Application.scala:88) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at controllers.Application$$anonfun$postUpload$1.apply(Application.scala
:88) ~[na:na]
```

my play version :2.1.5
my scala:2.10.4

I am getting error of time out exception while I am calling web service while for another web service it is working fine while  I am calling another web service getting this error can someone tell me what I can do for resolving this issue.
or can some one tell me how can I increase time out for response in play 2.1.5

Comment: make sure that the service which causing timeout is responing in a reasonable time. timeout happens when service is not responsing in a predefined or given time

Comment: I have checked  my web  service log  it is complete and  it gave response and then end and it gave response in 4000ms and I am giving 120000ms as time out exception   don't know why server is not getting response

Comment: in post man client also it is giving response 4000ms

Comment: why play server is not getting response I don't know

Comment: Even I increased timeout exception as 300000ms still getting same error

Comment: did you try without headers or body parts? sometimes improper headers and body parts can lead problems on server side, BTW why not using Play's WS?

Comment: I have to send data as multi part-from data because my web service is accepting data in this format only that's why using async http client and my web service is uploading data in databases this work is going fine  while I am calling  that web service and my webservice also giving response but play not getting response don't know why