# How to sent Scala FilePart[TemporaryFile]) as Java File?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I am trying to sent an file through multi-part form data using Scala and Play 2.4.6.

```
  def sendFile(file: FilePart[TemporaryFile]): Option[Future[Unit]] = {

     val asyncHttpClient:AsyncHttpClient = WS.client.underlying

     val postBuilder = asyncHttpClient.preparePost(s"${config.ocrProvider.host}")

     val multiPartPost = postBuilder
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("access_token",s"${config.ocrProvider.accessToken}"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("typename",s"${config.ocrProvider.typeName}"))
      .addBodyPart(new StringPart("action",s"${config.ocrProvider.actionUpload}"))
      .addBodyPart(new FilePart(???)
}
```

I'm new on Scala and Play, and i would like to sent file method attribute as new FilePart. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just like

```
 .addBodyPart(new FilePart("myFile", new File("app/controllers/Application.scala")))
```

You could find a full example of post in play-scala in my answer here: [Sending multi part form data in post method in play/scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715340/sending-multi-part-form-data-in-post-method-in-play-scala)